# require-config: Uncaught Error: Script error for: datatables.net

Tags: requirejs, magento2

I am working on making and formatting tables using JS, **datatables.net** website.

and I make table successfully , and included file easily.

but now I need to add a button on top which is used to download csv format of a table data. but its not working for me and providing below error.

> Uncaught Error: Script error for: datatables.net

```
    require([
    'jquery', 
    'mage/mage', 
    'jquery/ui',
    'A2bizz_Custom/js/jquery.dataTables.min',
    'A2bizz_Custom/js/dataTables.buttons.min'], function($){
         var table = $('#a2bizz_custom').DataTable({
                        dom: 'B',                   
                        buttons: ['csv']
                    });
    });
```

I am able to add datatable using **jquery.dataTables.min** but When including second js **dataTables.buttons.min** , then I a getting above error.

Looking for helping hand.

thanks

Comment: you have to require `datatables.net`.

Comment: Can you show your requirejs.config?